# How to use Qemu with a binary file

Tags: mips, qemu, emulation

i want to use Qemu with a raw binary data taken from an embedded router: the .bin file contains Uboot and a linux kernel for a mips microprocessor.
I'm trying to simulate the system with qemu without any result.
Is it possible? Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean _specifically_ when you say "without any result"? There are a number of `qemu` commands and options and it appears that `mips` is well supported. Please edit your question to include details about what you've tried (e.g. specific commands) and what results you've gotten (e.g. specific error messages)

Comment: MIPS the CPU may be supported, but that doesn't mean that "some random embedded router board" is supported -- most embedded hardware has different devices depending on the board and SoC so if it isn't something QEMU models then it won't work.